# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in my code

Tags: c

I can't find a mistake in my code.
When I run it, it says segmentation fault(core dumped).
I read topics, but couldn't understand my mistake.
It's in appropriate directory.
I would be very thankful if some can help me.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 50

int main(){

    int i,n,j,t;
    double a[MAX];

    do{
        printf("enter a lenght of your array");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    }while (n<1 || n>MAX);

    printf("enter the elements of your array");
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("a[%d]= ", i);
        scanf("%lf", &a[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<n/2;i++){
        for(j=n-1;j>n/2;j++){
            t=a[i];
            a[i]=a[j];
            a[j]=t;
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("%lf", a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Run in a debugger to catch the crash, and see where in your code it happens. Then examine the values of variables to try and figure out why it happens.

Comment: You should check that the indexes used (`i`, and `n`) are not out of bounds (`0<=i<MAX`).

Comment: Yes, using a debugger would let you know that the failing line is `a[i]=a[j];`. Still using this debugger (or just add a printf of i and j values) would have shown you that j is always increasing. At at a moment `a[j]` crashes.

Answer (score 4):

```
  for(i=0;i<n/2;i++){
      for(j=n-1;j>n/2;j++){     /*    <--- This loop      */
```

In this loop you should decrement `j` , so do `j--`.

Because `j=n-1` and you increment it , and `a` has `max` number of elements, so this loop will access index out of bounds and cause *undefined behaviour*.

So you should decrement `j` in loop.

Comment: how can i swap first and last, second and penultimate in array ?

Comment: @Luka I don't think you need two loops for that .  Increment `i` and decrement `j` in single loop. Initialize them as `i=0` and `j=n-1` , and swap the numbers .

Comment: @Luka Just this loop will do  - `for(i=0,j=n-1;(i<n/2)||(j>n/2);i++,j--)`  and do swapping inside this loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is in the line

```
for(j=n-1;j>n/2;j++){
```

In this line you are incrementing the value of j beyond its allocated limits.  And you are trying to access a[j]. This is an example of **Out of bound Array access**. i.e. you are trying to access that element of the array which you have not declared.

It might be possible that a[j] lies in a memory location that's not owned by your currently running program (which will probably cause your program to crash with something like a segmentation fault). Probably this is the reason for the segmentation fault in your code.

Edit: After running gdb on your program, I found that that the program terminated with signal **SIGSEGV**

SIGSEGV is the signal sent to a process when it makes an invalid memory reference, or segmentation fault.

I suggest you to also use gdb for debugging your errors